# Strange patterns when booting from USB

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation, usb, 20.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my Windows machine (HP Pavilion with a Ryzen CPU).

I have followed the instructions [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview) to create a bootable USB stick.

Initially I tried the 20.04 Desktop LTS build using the above instructions. I got to the boot menu and selected Ubuntu and saw this screen:

[image: Error from 20.04 attempt]

Notice the strange purple and green lines on the screen on top, and the strange patterns further down. Sorry the image quality isn't high, but that white marks at the center of the screen are not English test - just garbled gibberish.

I figured I would try the 18.04 Desktop LTS and found a similar result.

[image: Error from 18.04 attempt]

Has anyone encountered this issue? Since I am not quite sure how to describe this without pictures it's hard to search for any troubleshooting advice.

Comment: Have you tried booting `nomodeset`? When booting the Rufus USB press the `Shift` key. If Language screen comes up press `Esc` and select `nomodeset` from the list. if after pressing `Shift` the grub menu comes up, press `e` and at the end of the line that starts with linux type a space and `nomodeset.` this should ensure you start in safe graphics mode.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron - thank you! I was able to install Ubuntu using this method.